# Verify that X^2 is a continuous random variable..

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let X be a continuous random variable. Verify that the following function is continuous random variable.
$X^2$.

From the definition of a continuous random variable, I know that $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x \in R$. I can't see how I'm gonna come up with a 0 and write it formally but I tried  $P(X^2=x^2)=0$ if X is a continuous RV

Comment: If you prove that $P(X^2=x)=0$, how exactly does that help with showing that $X^2$ is a continuous variable?

Comment: I would be using that idea to get the answer. I think that just writing $P(X^2=0)=P(X=0)=0$ and then creating a $y\inR$ in order to write $P(X^2=y)=0 iff y<0$ and so on.. But I think it's too easy to just create those expression this way. please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: $X$ being a continuous variable, means that there exists a function $f$, so that $P(X\in A) = \int_A f(x) dx$ for any measurable set $A$. We need to show that there exists a function $g(x)$ such that $P(X^2\in A) = \int_A g(x) dx$.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin The thing is I just started to work on the chapter and such expression do not make sense to me. But thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X^2=x) = P(X=-x^\frac12)+P(X=x^\frac12)$ for $x > 0$. $P(X^2=0)=P(X=0)$ .$P(X^2=x)=0$ for $x<0$.

Comment: how have you come up with the $X^2=0$ ?

Comment: Since we are dealing with real numbers, $X^2=0$ iff $X=0$.

Comment: From what you wrote I should understand that just tweaking the expression can give you the answer. But I still think that answer is too simple since I can't see where and why you started to implement the P(X^2=0)

Comment: We want to calculate $P(X^2=x)$, so I simply "break" the question into three special cases: $x>0$, $x=0$ and $x<0$, as their behavior differs.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood I can write my answer the following way: Since $P(X^2=x)$ with $x \in R$.
x can be =0 , <0 and >0. In the first case, $P(X^2=0)=0$ which is $P(X=x)=0$. In the second case, $P(X^2=y)$ with y<0 which gives P(`impossible`)=0. And for the last one, $P(X^2=y)$ with y>0, $P( X=-squareroot(y) )+ P( X=sauarerroot(y) )=0 $
Since it's 0 in all these cases then from the definition X is a continuous random variable.